# How to pad 0 while copying files in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a=0000001;
    for (int i=0; i <= 5; i++)
    {

        File.Copy(@"C:\SR\30758668.pdf", @"C:\SR\"+a+"_30758668.pdf",true);
        a++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nSuccessful");
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

I've written above program to copy 1 file 5 times with leading string.
like this file `30758668.pdf` should be created as `0000001_30758668.pdf`,`` 0000002_30758668.pdf`, ``0000003_30758668.pdf` like wise.

now its creating files with `1_30758668.pdf` and `2_30758668.pdf` I don't want this way.

I'm not getting where to convert to integer or string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And `int` does not have formatting; 01 is the same as 1 is the same as 00000001 - they are all just 1.

Use:

```
 .... + a.ToString().PadLeft(7,'0') + ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format. Ie:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\SR\30758668.pdf", "C:\SR\" + a.Tostring("000000") + "_30758668.pdf", true);
```

Or use String.Format for better string building:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\SR\30758668.pdf", String.Format(@"C:\SR\{0}_30758668.pdf", a.ToString("000000")), true);
```

Comment: Could also put the format specifier in the string: `{0:00000000}`

Comment: Or use {0:D7} to achieve similar result.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to padding explicitly is to just use the Dx format specifier on `ToString()` or in `string.Format()`:

For example:

```
File.Copy(@"C:\SR\30758668.pdf", @"C:\SR\" + a.ToString("D7") + "_30758668.pdf",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify leading zeros on numeric data types. 
You need to convert it to String and use PadLeft to pad it with the character you want. The first parameter of PadLeft indicates the total width of the string you want, and the second parameter indicates which character will be used for padding.

```
int a=1; 

for (int i=0; i <= 5; i++) 
 { 

            File.Copy(@"C:\SR\30758668.pdf", @"C:\SR\"+ a.ToString().PadLeft(7, "0")+ "_30758668.pdf",true); 

        } 

        Console.WriteLine("\nSuccessful"); 
        Console.ReadLine(); 

    }
```